# It is possible to specify that all positional args be of either one or other argument type?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I have been using the crap out of the `typing` module because I have discovered it makes going back to read and understand my code about 3x easier. It also makes pycharm twice as useful.

I am aware that to specify the type of single OR positional arguments, one can do this:

```
def f(*args: int = 0) -> None:
    #  integers are expected for args
    pass
```

Furthermore, if the positional arguments can be of multiple types, you can use `Union` to handle this case:

```
from typing import Union

def f(*args: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    #  integers OR strings are expected for args
    pass
```

My question is: is there a way to tell the type checker to make sure the `args` are EITHER ALL `int`s, OR ALL `str`s, but not a mixture of both, but not limited to ONLY `int`s or ONLY `str`s?

Comment: It just occurred to me that this might be a use case for overloading...

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want to use a `TypeVar`:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T', int, str) # can be either int or str, but not both in a single call

def f(*args: T) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: makes sense! didn't even think of doing it that way.